# Will this cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

If I declare a static queue like this inside a public class:

```
public class c
{
  private string[] s={"a","b","c"};
  private static Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>(s);

  static private void SomeMethod()
  {
     private string[] s2 = {"123","345"};
     // somewhere in here I reassign the queue q = new Queue<string>(s2);
  }
}
```

Will my action cause a memory leak in C#? Would the garbage collection claim back the possible unused memory?

Answer (score 8):

No. Nothing there will cause a leak.

Once the object that `q` referenced is no longer referenced anywhere, it will be garbage collected appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't cause a memory leak. The original queue is deallocated by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

If any object that 'q' referenced is no longer referenced anywhere, the garbage collector will collect it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth your time to read one of the many articles on Garbage Collection and how it works e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

To answer your question though, no - that won't cause a memory leak.